# Adding random generated numbers in Python

Tags: python

I have to write a program that generates a list of random generated numbers. At the end of the list I need the total of the numbers.

For example;
3, 5, 2, 1, 8

The total is 19.

I'm not sure how to get the total of the generated numbers to appear, and to appear on the next line. "The total is 19" has to appear on the next line. Thank you!

```
import random

def randnums():
    for count in range(6):
       number = random.randint(1, 6)
       print(number, end=" ")
randnums()
```

Comment: The program is supposed to display 6 numbers, please ignore the fact that my example only shows 5 numbers.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, I'd recommend going over your notes and other instructional materials.

Comment: You need to add a running total `total += number` that you print at the end of the for loop.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have been for the last day. Everything I've tried won't work so I'm trying to get some help. I'm trying to figure this out on my own but I'm at a complete loss at how to continue.

Comment: Your first sentence suggest you want a list of numbers, but your code generates just one at a time. Do you actually want a `list`? Have you learned list comprehensions yet?

Comment: `total = sum([random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(6)])`

Answer (score 0):

Just define an integer variable and add the corresponding number with it for every iteration.

```
import random

def randnums():
    num = 0
    for count in range(6):
       number = random.randint(1, 6)
       print(number, end=" ")
       num += number

    print("\n"+str(num))
randnums()
```