# i've generated random numbers. Now i want to add all the numbers that are generated. What is the code to add them

Tags: python, random, sum

i've generated random numbers. Now i want to add all the numbers that are generated.

```
import random
x= 0
while x<10:
    number = random.randrange(1,10)
    print(number)
    x=x+1
```

I expect the output

```
3 9 6 6 4 5 4 7 3 1

Sum: 48
```

Comment: You need to write code to do this, but it appears you have not yet tried to do that.

Comment: I'm stuck. Tried a few codes but all end in errors.

Comment: Hi! This question has already been asked. Try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32622081/4844273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a total variable and add the generated number to the total

```
import random

x = 0
total = 0
while x<10:
    number = random.randrange(1,10)
    print(number)
    total += number
    x=x+1
print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want very few lines of code, another option could be a list-comprehension, like this:

```
import random

num_list = [
    random.randrange(1, 10)
    for _ in range(10)]

print(num_list)
print(sum(num_list))
```

The output would be something like this:

```
[6, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 6, 8, 6, 1]
38
```

---

As user @Andrej pointed out, starting with `Python 3.6` you can use the function [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) to get the same result:

```
import random
num_list = random.choices(range(1, 10), k=10)
print(num_list)
print(sum(num_list))
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would add only `random.choices(range(1, 10), k=10)` for Python 3.6+

Comment: replace your first line with this `print(*num_list, sep=", ")`, it removes the brackets.

Comment: @AndrejKesely it's nice, thank you. but @Ralf I get an error like this from the last print statement. `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera the code works for me. Could you show the full stacktrace of the error so I can try to indentify the origin of the error?

Comment: @Ralf earlier your code is working fine, It's the best answer and I voted it. But now it's not working, I don't know the reason. When I print the `num_list`, it displays the list of integers, the problem with using `sum()`.

Comment: @Ralf I just close my terminal and re run your code with new terminal. Now it's working fine. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

try creating a new variable and add your random number to it

```
import random
x= 0
sum = 0
while x<10:
    number = random.randrange(1,10)
    print(number)
    sum = sum + number
    x=x+1
print(sum)
```

Comment: Tried it, but it keeps adding within the while loop. But i'm trying that the sum should be displayed explicitly after all the numbers are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
import random

num = 0

for i in range(10):
    random_number = random.randrange(1,10)
    num += random_number
    print(random_number, end=' ')

print(f'\nsum: {num}')

# 4 9 9 9 2 2 1 9 5 5
# sum: 55
```

I tried with Python 3.7 version.

Comment: You're welcome @Aashishm, it print the random numbers in single line like your expected output of the question. If you want multiple lines, just remove `end=' '` from the first print statement.